# search and move all files in directory but keep both files in batch

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, copy

I want to copy allot of (sound)files, these are all different sounds, but the most of file names are all the same.. and the files are in sub folders that have random characters as their name.

but **how do i search and copy all sound files in all random sub folders to one folder? but keep both files that are double and do not overwrite them**, like:

> Instead of only:    Ambient.wav
>
> To this:     Ambient(1).wav  Ambient(2).wav Ambient(3).wav etc...

I use Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy certain files (w/o folder hierarchy), but do not overwrite existing files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497667/how-to-copy-certain-files-w-o-folder-hierarchy-but-do-not-overwrite-existing) 
I think that this does almost exactly what you want except maybe minor changes (in the accepted answer instead of copying only the first one you can add a variable and add its numerical value to the file name instead) plus there's `xxcopy` which does exactly that)

Comment: but it doesn't copy the sound files from all random directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 IF EXIST "%destdir%\%%~nxa" (
  SET notfound=Y
  FOR /L %%b IN (1,1,999) DO IF DEFINED notfound IF NOT EXIST "%destdir%\%%~na(%%b)%%~xa" (
   ECHO(COPY "%%a" "%destdir%\%%~na(%%b)%%~xa"
   SET "notfound="
  )
  IF DEFINED notfound ECHO(Failed to COPY "%%a"
 ) ELSE (ECHO(COPY "%%a" "%destdir%\%%~nxa"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

The required COPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files.

Naturally, the `copy` could become `move` if you prefer.

The destination directory should not be a subdirectory of the source.

You could add `>nul` to the `copy` to suppress the `copied` message if desired.

I've used a mask of `*` for all files. If you only want say `.jpg`s, then change `"%sourcedir%\*"` to `"%sourcedir%\*.jpg"`